# Bootstrap Collapse conflict when expand one more item

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have made a section with bootstrap. With in this section i added two div for adding bootstrap Collapse  there first one is working good but second one doesn't work. In second div it only open content but does not Collapse

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/188550847/problem/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO single](http://jsfiddle.net/4pxywkwj/2/)  and [DEMO full](http://jsfiddle.net/4pxywkwj/2/embedded/result/)

You have to set different `ids` and `data-parent` for each `accordion`.

change

`<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">`

to

`<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-1">`

and

`<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">`

to

`<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapseTwo">`

Hier is the full code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="section-title item_bottom text-center" style="opacity: 1; bottom: 0px;">
        <div>
            <span class="fa fa-cogs fa-2x"></span>
        </div>
        <h1 class="white">Why<span>Us?</span></h1>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="faqh">Our Strength</h2>
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapseOne" class="">
          About Costing
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
       <ul>
                    <li>No capital expense </li>
                    <li>No operations cost</li>
                    <li>Up to 60% cost savings when compared to current offshore costs</li>

       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapseTwo" class="">
          How we operate?
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
       <ul>
                    <li>Robust process. </li>
                    <li>Flexible model</li>
                    <li>Transparent operations</li>

                </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapseThree" class="">
         Team work
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>Work single project at a time</li>
                    <li>Availability of resources with skills hard to find locally</li>
                    <li>Low employee attrition.</li>
            <li>Employees with previous experience in working directly <br/>  with international (UK, US &amp; EU) clients</li> 
                    <li>Complete management control over your dedicated resources. </li>
                        <li>Our engagement model allows you to treat and manage your <br/>resources as your own employees</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapsefour" class="collapsed">
          Quality Assurance 
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>As client has direct control over output or result of  candidate, <br/> quality will be maintained as per standards at client end.</li>
                <li>As quality people in terms of experience and skills are involved <br/>quality can be better controlled as per requirements</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapsefive" class="collapsed">
          Messages
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsefive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>All outsourcing deals will be strictly confidential and not disclosed to any media.</li>
                    <li>NDA is signed.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#collapsesix" class="collapsed">
          Anything More?
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsesix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <li>Candidate is dedicated for single client and so can give 100% time and <br/>attention to a client company. This avoids delays in the work output.</li>
                    <li>Easy agreement process and terms. </li>
                    <li>Free from legal issues.</li>
                    <li>We provide pilot program of 2 months before large duration contract.</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



    </div>


<!-- Accordion 2 -->



    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="faqh">Question about us</h2>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#one" class="collapsed">
          Why I need to 
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="one" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
       <ul>
        <li>Cost benefits.</li>
        <li>You can concentrate more on to increase customer base or other core business process.

        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#Two" class="">
          How much needed 
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="Two" class="panel-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>You can hire candidate for minimum of 4 months.  But pilot program can be run for 1 month.</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#Three" class="">
          Is our service cost effective and qualified? 
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="Three" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>1.  Yes! Our service is about 40% less costly compared to existing outsourcing service providers. You can hire 3 years experience person in general skills at an average cost of USD 1800$ per month.</li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#four">
          Is there project manager for each project? 
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="four" class="panel-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>o   For each outsourcing project where more than 3 resources are working, we provide dedicated project manager at free of cost. He will be in contact with client as well as have responsibility of managing entire project. </li>
            <li>This project manager cost will be bearded by Nimetler Technologies.In all other cases, Nimetler in house project manager will. </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#five">
          How you work effectively with clients?
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="five" class="panel-collapse in" style="height: auto;">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>A dedicated or shared project manager to manage work of candidates.</li>
            <li>Use of cost-effective communication tools.</li>
            <li>Easy-to-use project management tools for instant access to the status of your project.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-2" href="#six">
          Anything More?
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="six" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h3>If candidate not found result oriented during job what action will be taken?</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>If client is not satisfied with any candidates’ work he will be immediately replaced with alternate candidate. </li>
            <li>Nimetler will not charge client on the day complaint is officially registered in given format. Also candidate will be asked to stop work.</li>
            <li>In the case client can’t stop work due to certain reason, but complaint has been registered, Nimetler will charge 50% of amount negotiated till new candidate is recruited. </li>
        </ul>
          <hr/>
        <h3>What precaution you take to tackle such situations?</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>During interview process we select at least 2 candidates. Out of it second person is backup resource. So work will not get affected. </li>
            </ul>
            <hr/>

            <h3>Who manages candidates?</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>As all candidates are our employees, it is our responsibility to manage them. Client need to just provide assignment and check work done.  </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```